# How can I store user information online for my Alexa skill?

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

I am making an alexa skill that accesses a database and gets an access key to use for future services. I currently have all my code written in a NodeJs lambda function and the https requests are made to get this access code. The problem is that everytime the skill is invoked, the code has to go through the entire process of getting the access key, even though it is good for hours. My question is, is there any way to store the access key somewhere, so that my code can grab it associated with a certain user?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to use "Account linking " So for each request from alexa you will have a token that identify the user